# htaccess rewrite rule not redirecting

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have recently re-coded a website and I have the following line which works great for making a friendly looking URL.

```
RewriteRule ^mydir/([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?menu=mydir&vid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, I have found out that there are some old links out there which have an altogether different look to them which I also need to rewrite.

So I tried this...

```
RewriteRule ^mydir/detail/\?id=([^/]+)?$ /page.php?menu=mydir&vid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^mydir/([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?menu=mydir&vid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The url containing `/detail/` does not rewrite though. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match query string using `RewriteRule`. Change your rules to this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^mydir/detail/?$ /page.php?menu=mydir&vid=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^mydir/([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?menu=mydir&vid=$1 [L,QSA]
```